# Does data on Network Buffer show in Process Memory Usage?

Tags: memory, network-programming

I am using process explorer to view the memory consumption of one of my services after complaints that it "appears to be leaking memory"

I watch "private bytes" as my service is running, and sure enough it keeps going up at a rate of about 2MB/sec indefinitely.

After writing several tests looking for leaks, I found none. However, I did discover that if I turn logging off then the memory usage no longer climbs.

My theory is that the process simply cannot keep up with the number of messages being sent over the network to it while also logging them all to disk.

My question(s) then:

1 ) Will messages continually build up on the "network buffer?"

1a) What determines how many can queue up there before my service makes calls to recv to grab them?

2) Will the process use/appear to use more memory as messages queue up there?

I am using Windows 10 and Server 2012 R2, boost::ASIO (which uses Winsock), in native C++.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the socket receive buffer, it is fixed in size and not part of the process address space.